# Border acting weird

Tags: css, border

I have a simple frame.

Code I use for borders:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #E1E1E1;
```

Every other element looks okay, but this one kinda acts weird. Only top border.

```css
.frame {
  height: 585px;
}

.frame:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #E1E1E1;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame" background-image:url(...png)>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: @dippas Updated.

Comment: Can you please describe what you mean by "weird"? Also, why don't you use `border` instead of `box-shadow`?

Comment: Can you post a working fiddle for same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** : `background-image:url(...png)` is not correct, you need to wrap it into a style attr if you want inline styling, so `style="background-image:url(...png)"` is correct. (also image path should be a valid one)

**Second** : The border is 5px tick and appears only on hover, by default it will add height/width to the element, if you want to keep the size of the image on hover you should think of using a `box-shadow: inset 0p 0p 0p 5px #E1E1E1;` Also if you are wondering why it looks like a border instead of a shadow, see this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp . You are setting a blur of 0px s0 that's why.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!